# How do I use the gun that comes with Robin's Biohazard suite in Lego Batman 2?

Tags: lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes

I can get Robin to ready the weapon by pressing the circle button, but I can't get the gun to do anything. How do you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gun can shoot toxic waste, but it first needs to suck some up before it can shoot it out.  Use the action button in a toxic waste pool to suck it up, then you'll be able to fire it out.